# Any variety is a subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Lemma I.4.1 of Hartshorn's *Algebraic Geometry*, states that two morphisms of varieties $\phi,\psi:X\to Y$ which are equal on a nonempty open subset $U\subset X$ are equal on all of $X$. In the proof, Hartshorne states that we may assume $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ for some $n$.

Why can we make this assumption?

Comment: At this point in the book, *variety* means an affine, quasi-affine, projective or quasi-projective variety (see p. 15).  Projective and quasi-projective varieties are subsets of projective space by definition, and we can embed any affine space into projective space as one of the standard affine open sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say, the most general notion of variety in Chapter 1 of Hartshorne is a quasiprojective variety.  Later in chapter 2, Hartshorne introduces the more general notion and has remarks about this on page 105.  See for example [Hironaka's counterexample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka%27s_example).